# How can I return a JSON result to a Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have got this simple form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateProductFromAjaxForm","Product" , 
                  null, 
                  new AjaxOptions() {  HttpMethod = "post", OnSuccess = "getresult" },
                  null))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Next" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And, for testing, a simple controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateProductFromAjaxForm(CreateProductModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return new JsonResult()
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new { result = "error" }
            };
        }

       //add to database

        return new JsonResult()
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            Data = new { result = "success"}
        };
    }
```

I have added these to the Web.Config:

```
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

and these to my script bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"
                    ));
```

After clicking the "Submit" button, the resulting page just shows:

```
{"result":"success"}
```

I would expect that I could handle the result in the `OnSuccess="getresult"` handler, but it doesn't seem to work.

Basically I am using the `Ajax.BeginForm` mainly for the clientside validation.

Can you tell me whats wrong?

UPDATE: I added the  `HttpMethod = "post"` to the AjaxOptions.

UPDATE: The `getresult`, is defined above the `Ajax.BeginForm` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var getresult = function (data) {
        alert(data.result);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of your `getresult` method?

Comment: Put a dummy alert inside the javascript function, just to see if it is being invoked, something like: `alert('hello')`

Comment: @RuiJarimba: no luck with the `alert('hi');` either.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you need to include `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't have this in my script directory. I am using MVC 5. Should I download it?

Comment: Yes, use NuGet Packages to find Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax.

Comment: Life saver in 2017

Answer (score 8):

JsonResult is just a kind of ActionResult derived class that indicates that this action will return JSON instead of a view or something else.

For example:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateProductFromAjaxForm","Product" , null, 
              new AjaxOptions() {  OnSuccess = "getresult" }, null))
```

This will generate a  element which will send an AJAX request when submitted to the action. For this to work you need to include the following script to your page:

Now all that's left is to write this onSuccess javascript function and process the JSON results returned by the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var onSuccess = function(data) {
    alert(data.result);
};
</script
```

Answer (score 6):

in page

```
new AjaxOptions() {  
    OnSuccess = "getresult", 
}
```

in javascript

```
function getresult(data){
   alert(data.x);
}
```

in c#

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateProductFromAjaxForm(CreateProductModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Json("error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

   //add to database

    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the HTTP method:

```
new AjaxOptions() {  
    OnSuccess = "getresult", 
    HttpMethod = "post" 
}
```

Example:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateProductFromAjaxForm", "Product" , null, new AjaxOptions() {  OnSuccess = "getresult", HttpMethod = "post" }, null))
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately; no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with my project. Ajax library is not being loaded is the problem. When I checked my `bundleconfig` and my layout file, it did have the include but I'm including the absolute name for ajax library like

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryajax").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));
```

My friend asked me to use the wild card instead. Surprisingly 
`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryajax").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax*"));` started including the ajax library.

Now my `OnSuccess` functions are loading as expected rather than looking at the blank screen with json response on it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
var getresult = function (data) {
    alert(data.result);
};
```

Try

```
function getresult(data) {
    alert(data.result);
};
```

Comment: Again; no success. I even tried to omit the `data` parameter: same result.