# Asp.net MVC JsonResult succes Message

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my Controller :

```
    public JsonResult Success() { return Json(new { Success = true, Message = "Data Added Succefully" }); }
    public JsonResult Error(string message) { return Json(new { Success = false, Message = message }); }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateAjax(TAUX taux)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (short i in taux.SelectItems)
                {
                    taux.CAT_ID = i;
                    db.TAUX.Add(taux);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                }
                return Success();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                return Error(err.Message);
            }
        }

        ViewBag.CAT_ID = new SelectList(db.CATEGORIE, "CAT_ID", "LIBELLE", taux.CAT_ID);
        ViewBag.C_GARANT = new SelectList(db.GARANTIE, "C_GARANT", "LIB_ABREGE", taux.C_GARANT);

        return Error("The server wasn't able to do something right now.");
    }
```

This is My PartialView `CreateAjax`:

```
@model pfebs0.Models.TAUX
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateAjax", "Taux", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
{...}
```

And this is my View `Index` :

```
@model IEnumerable<pfebs0.Models.TAUX>
...
     <script>
         $.ajax({
             url: "/",
             method: "POST",
             data: getMyData(),

             success: function (json) {
                 if (json.Success) {
                     alert("Wow, everything was fine!");
                 } else {
                     alert(json.Message);
                 }
             },

             // This will be trigered whenever your ajax call fails (broken ISP link, etc).
             error: function () {
                 alert("Something went wrong. Maybe the server is offline?");
             }
         });

</script> 
...
       @Html.ActionLink("Ajouter", "Create", "Taux",
                new { id = "btnAdd", @class="btn btn-default"})
</p>
...
    @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            $('.modal-dialog').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#modalDiv').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
....
 </script> }
```

What I'm trying to do here is to show success alert after Insertionn but after Insertion I'm redirected to new Page `Localhost/Taux/ajaxCreate` where It show me this message `{"Success":true,"Message":"Data Added Succefully"}` instead of showing PopUp with success message in `Index` Page. What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(....))
{   }
```

with the appropiate parameters.

See [How can I return a JSON result to a Ajax.BeginForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746784/how-can-i-return-a-json-result-to-a-ajax-beginform) for details.

There might be some issues with the script as well.
What are you trying to do with:

```
<script>
     $.ajax({
         url: "/",
         method: "POST",
         data: getMyData(),
```

?

**UPDATE**
Ok, this should work:

1) use your original

```
@using (Html.BeginForm
```

2) put the ajax call in a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postData()
    {
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("CreateAjax", "Taux")',
             method: "POST",
             data: $('#form').serialize(),

            ....
    }
```

3) change the `type="submit"` to `type="button"` at the submit button and add:

```
onclick="postData()"
```

attribute.

4) change ajax url:

```
url: '@Url.Action("CreateAjax", "Taux")',
```

5) add the change the getMyData function function

```
data: $('#form').serialize(),
```

Comment: following your link, when i click on submit nothing happend it dosn't submit my form.

Comment: Are you using a submit button to post the form?

Comment: yes `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Valider</button>`

Comment: To get Returned Data From Json Result

Comment: No Always Reditecting to blank page where success message is showin

Comment: :| ... in that case I would recommend to debug the javascript to see if the post is actually executing. If you are using chrome or firefox with fire bug you can press F12 or start firebug to inspect the HTTP traffic and set breakpoints at the javascript lines

Comment: I'm not familiar with Javascript but i tried to debug the code so when he's on this line `data: getMyData()` he jump directly to the new page he dosn't continue to the rest of Script code

Comment: @Chlebta: can you post the getMyData function in your original post?

Comment: I have no GetMyData function just see over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505985/asp-net-mvc-success-alert-after-form-submit . If you got any other Idea how to show success message I will apriciate that. and even when I delete GetMy data Always same issue

Comment: @Chlebta: added step 5

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52712/discussion-between-chlebta-and-stefan)